# Java Method Confusion

Tags: java, string, methods, compareto

In Java, when for example you say string1.compareTo(string2), how is the compareTo method accessing the string1.  I see the method takes in the second string but how does it compare it to the first if it is not getting passed along?

Comment: It *is* getting passed along.  The compiler arranges for both `string1` and `string2` to get put on the stack in this case.

Comment: string1 is the reference on which you dispatch the method.

Comment: If it helps, you can imagine that `string1` is passed in implicitly, as if there was a hidden parameter `String this` at the beginning of every method declaration.  Thought that's not exactly what happens..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

compareTo() is a member function of Class String, this means that for invoking this function you need an Object of Type String. So when you say string1.compareTo(string2) , this means that you are invoking **compareTo()** function on the String object '**string1**' and passing '**string2**' as the argument.

Answer (score -1):

I think this little 'illustration' could help you

```
Class String {

    public int CompareTo(String string2)
    {
        if (this==string2) return 1; //The == is completely wrong here but it gives you an idea on how it works
        else return 0;
    }

}
```

When you call `string1.CompareTo(string2);` in the method, `this` will reference the object itself, so here it references `string1`

Comment: Point you are missing, is the explanation that `this` is the object `string1` from the question

Comment: This is factually wrong - the signature of `compareTo` is actually `public int compareTo(String other)`.  Further, if two elements are the same reference, the contract of `Comparable` mandates that it returns 0.

Comment: I know.. I'm not trying to explain the CompareTo function.. I just wrote this to explain the this pointer, as the OP wanted..

Comment: @Adri1du40 It might be obvious, but it is also obvious that that is the question that OP is asking, I am guessing OP skipped a few OOP classes and jumped straight into Java tutorials